# When converting direct reporting into indirect reporting should “I had” become “he had had”?

Tags: reported-speech

I was given the following:

> "I could not get into the house because I had lost my key, so I had to break a window", he said.

To convert it into indirect reporting, I wrote the following:

> He said that he could not get into the house because he had lost his key, so he had had to break a window.

However, my instructor told me this is wrong and that instead of "had had" it would just be a single "had". In other words:

> He said that he could not get into the house because he had lost his key, so he had to break a window.

I'm confused as to why this is the case since as far as I can tell you need another "had" to correct the tense when converting to indirect reporting. Could someone please explain why this is wrong? What are the rules for these kinds of situations?

Comment: Your instructor is mistaken. It's perfectly okay (but not *obligatory*) to use Past Perfect ***had had*** instead of Simple Past ***had*** in the cited context. Same as you could have used ***had been obliged** [to break a window]* rather than ***was obliged...*** - both tenses are fine.

Comment: He said on Friday that he could not get into the house on Thursday (and so had to break a window to get in) because he had lost his key on Wednesday.

Comment: This reminds me of the famous sentence with the same word repeated 11 times: "Peter, where Paul had had "had", had had "had had"; "had had" had had the teacher's approval". In this case, it seems, "had" had the teacher's approval instead!